# Landlord asking for income verification after lease is signed?

Tags: residential-lease

My landlord is asking for me to give additional income verification of proof but we have already signed a lease and already payed the third month of rent. Especially considering the landlord is silent and refused me asking for a repair to the house because it's "AS-IS" - I asked 3 times with declined due to AS-IS, but now they want income verification.

It actually perturbs me that we have a signed lease, I did not agree to additional income verification but I did say that I had additional income (which I do), but they want a more specific income verification than the email my boss sent me agreeing to the terms.

Especially because they refused me basic things for the house, and ignored me on multiple requests about the house for months, including the inspection and which utilities to set up, and how the fireplace works (is it working? propane? natural gas?) - they just ignored all of my communications.

Yet now they insist on MORE income proofs for the last 10% of my income, and I don't want to give it out of principle because for one they refused to make any concessions for me yet demand something for them, and two we already have a signed lease and I am paying rent and taking care of the house well. I can verify it but I don't like getting pushed around when they won't do anything for me when I want it. Why should I do something extra for them when they want it?

Can they demand this since we already have a signed lease?

Comment: City and state?

Comment: Regardless of whether it's required under your current lease, if your landlord wants it and you don't give it, they might decline to renew your lease when it expires (assuming that's allowed by applicable local law).  Would that be a problem for you?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but in some places, it may not be legal for the landlord to rent a house "as is" - or rather, they may still be responsible for the repairs regardless of what the lease says.  Worth looking into.

Comment: @NateEldredge That was my primary concern, about not renewing the lease and I hate moving, but I wouldn't have tho reveal this fear and weaken my position, as they may be equally unwilling to let a good paying tenant go when it's harder to find good tenants here. The last tenant left the house vacant for months without telling them.

Comment: Why don't you just straight ask the landlord what's the point in asking additional income verification if the lease has been ongoing already, and what they would do if you don't provide what they ask?

Answer (score 0):

> Can they demand this since we already have a signed lease?

No, meaning that the landlord's belated requirement is not binding.

Your statement "*I did not agree to additional income verification*" reflects that the landlord's requirement is not premised on the lease you signed. Parties to a contract cannot unilaterally impose belated conditions, which is what the landlord seemingly is trying to do.

Furthermore, the fact that you have been paying rent (timely, I presume) reflects that the landlord's insistence is unwarranted.